# Symfony Command LOAD DATA INFILE Error

Tags: mysql, symfony

I am using Symfony 3 and attempting to run Load Data Infile but I keep getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

- I have chmod'd all of the files and parent directories to 777
- I have tried LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
- I've tried this: grant file on *.* to xxxx@localhost identified by 'xxxx' and I get an #1045 - Access denied for user ... error.
- I've tried this: GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'xxxx'@'%' and get this error: #1045 - Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'%' (using password: YES)

Here are my server specs:

> mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.52 & Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

```
        $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file."'
                INTO TABLE ".$sqlTbl."
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                ($sqlColumns[0])";
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->executeQuery($sql);
            echo 'File created & inserted - sql_'.$dataDoc['file']."\n";
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            echo "LOAD DATA INFILE ERROR\n";
            echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
            exit;
        }
```

Not sure what else to do.

Comment: The problem is caused by insufficient SQL user rights - e.g. bad SQL user credentials. How do you provide username/password for DB access in the class/file where is the code above?

Comment: This is all handled by Symfony. All my other queries in this Command script work fine, just the Load Data Infile seems to have issues.

Comment: Which SQL do you use? And have you tried `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...` instead (just for testing)?

Comment: Its MySQL & yes I have tried it with LOCAL as well.

Comment: Sorry, you mentioned it - I'm blind or what :-/

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but just for sure, when did you use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...` the file was on you local PC and the path was correct? And you got same error?

Comment: Another thing - try `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'db_username'@'%';`

Comment: Yes, I've done this as well... GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'xxxxxx'@'localhost'; and no the file is not stored locally, it is on my server.

Comment: When `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...` the file is get from local not from server, so put it locally and try it - just to know if it works, for now.

Comment: I am running the exact same script locally and it works fine. On my server there is some issue with the file permission for mysql. It has nothing to do with the actually csv file itself.

Comment: The error, you mentioned, can be caused by four things - 1) the SQL user rights to file operations (already granted), 2) the SQL user right to the table (you sain another operations works well), 3) the file itself, resp. httpd access to the file (we don't know) and 4) some error, bug or whatever in particular mysqld on the server. So my thinking was - put the file locally, use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE...` and let's figure out if it works or not... Then you'll know if LOAD DATA doesn't work globaly on the server or it's an file access issue. Am I clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135797/discussion-between-largetuna-and-honza-rydrych).